# Parse javascript: Navigating pointers with get() and fetch()?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So I'm working on a web app (app A) that interfaces with another web app (app B). People can use app A, but app B only has accounts for workplaces.

I'm writing some code that looks at the currently logged in user, finds their workplace via a pointer attribute, then finds that workplace's "proxy user" (a user for that workplace that we use to log into app B). I'm using a bunch of fetch()s and then()s to do that, but I'm running into some problems.

Here are my questions:

1. I have no problem using "workplace_pointer" to gat what looks like a workplace object, but when I try to get "proxy_user_pointer," it returns undefined. Am I doing something wrong?
2. I get the feeling that this isn't idiomatic use of the Parse SDK. Should I be using a Query or something instead?

The offending code is below:

```
  Parse.User.current().fetch().then(function(user) {
    console.log("fetch success");
    var workplace = user.get("workplace_pointer");
    return (workplace);
  }).then(function(w) {
    w.fetch();
    return (w);
  }).then(function(workplace) {
    console.log(workplace); // Looks great, attributes look like they're present
    var puser = workplace.get("proxy_user_pointer");
    console.log(puser); // undefined... huh?
    return (puser);
  }).then(function(pu) {
    pu.fetch();
    return (pu);
  }).then(function(pu) {
    proxyUser = pu;
    console.log(proxyUser);

    // then we authenticate with proxyUser
  }, function(err) { console.log(err); });
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Does `workplace.get('proxy_user_pointer')` return a promise? If so you'll need to await that (i.e. add another `then`)

Comment: Where do `workplace` and `p` come from?

Comment: towerofnix: assuming workplace is a parse object (which is what it looks like), workplace.get("attr") should return another parse object according to the API reference: https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_get

Comment: Bergi: sorry, I changed some variable names to make the code more legible/less specific, and I missed those two. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

So I think I figured it out. fetch() is asynchronous, and I need to wait for it to return before get()-ing any attributes.

This snippet actually returns immediately:

```
[...].then(function(w) {
    w.fetch();
    return (w);
  }).then([...]
```

So I had to replace it with something that blocks until fetch() finishes:

```
[...].then(function(w) {
    return w.fetch().then(function(w) {return (w)});
}).then([...]
```

Thanks, folks! I hope this solution helps someone else one day.